# Making Child classes as Non Serializable in java

Tags: java, inheritance, oop, serialization

I have a class which implements Serializable. Now I extends this class and I want this extended class to be non Serializable. So how to do it?

For example. I have

```
class A implements Serializable.
```

and I have

```
class B extends A.
```

But I want class B to be Non Serializable.

Comment: Is this question actually about persistence?

Comment: This is particularly a problem with all the serializable Swing classes IMHO. When I pass a subclass of (say) `AbstractTableModel` (serializable) to a `JTable`, I usually don’t expect the `JTable` to serialize the model, still I cannot avoid the requirement that my subclass be serializable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have made clear, it's not possible for a subclass of a `Serializable` class to be non-`Serializable`.

If what you want is for the subclass' attributes not to be serialized, one option is to make them all transient.

If you need more than that (you don't want super class fields to be serialized), override `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)` and `readObject(ObjectInputStream)` as outlined here - https://web.archive.org/web/20120626144013/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization

Comment: The link on Sun.com is no longer valid. Is this the same article? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

Comment: @spaaarky21 Nope, that's not the same article. I've updated the link to archive.org now.

Comment: if someone uses that does it violate it Liskov substituion method.

Answer (score 20):

You can't remove the interface, but you can prevent serialization at run-time:

```
class B extends A {
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
        throw new NotSerializableException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This could cause lots of issues, when someone checks whether you implement Serializable and then expects you to actually be serializable.

Comment: This is recommended by Sun.  See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/ (paragraph titled "Other Pointers".)

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and all.

Answer (score 4):

That's indeed not possible. Your best bet is to let B composite/decorate A.

```
public class B {
    private A a = new A();

    public void doSomething() {
        a.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't be done if `B` needs to be a subclass of, for example, `Throwable`, `Component`, or `Action`, all of which are Serializable.

Answer (score 3):

It will always be Serializable, though you could ensure nothing in the class ever gets serialized by making every member `transient`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering one of your comment (and assuming you are talking of JPA or Hibernate):

> But Any class which wants its object to be persisted should implement this. and I want my Class B's objects as non persistable.

If you don't want B to be persistent at all, don't mark it as `@Entity`. But it doesn't really make sense for B to extend A if B is not a persistent entity IMHO. This would be a bad use of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Need to implememnt readObject() and writeObject() Methods

Comment: You must read previous solutions proposed before adding your answer, in this case, yours has been already proposed and [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2229256/1387113) by @Jack Leow!.